# How do I use multiple OR operators in XPath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to combine three different OR opearators

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "[//img[contains(@src,'/BankPayProcessing-Icon.png')]|//span[contains(text(), 'Bank Pay Processing')]|//span[contains(text(), 'BankPay Processing')]")]
```

However, this is not working. I am not able to figure out why.
Can I get some help please?

Comment: Can you post a sample XML, so that we have a [mcve] to operate on?

Comment: unfortunately its on bunch of places

Comment: [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//img[contains(@src,'/BankPayProcessing-Icon.png')] | //span[contains(text(), 'BankPay Processing')] | //span[contains(text(), 'BankPay Processing')]")]

Answer (score 1):

The "or" operator in XPath is not "|", it is "or".

The "|" operator forms the union between two node-sets, it cannot be applied to a boolean value (such as the result of (A=B)).

It's easy to be misled when you see something like `match="x|y"` into thinking it matches "x or y". Actually it matches the union of x and y, that is, anything in the set of all x and y elements.

Comment: Cool let me try or in place of |

Comment: If an answer works for you, please tick the check-mark next to the answer so that everyone can see an answer has been accepted. There's no need for a "thankyou" comment.